# Hardware sensors in the phones

Tags: android, hardware, android-sensors

Starting from Android API v19, OS supports two new hardware elements, namely, step counter and step detector.

I found that Samsung Galaxy S5 and Nexus 5 have those hardware components.

Could You tell, please, some other phone models that are powered by Android OS and support those hardware elements?